# Append to file in HDFS (CDH 5.4.5)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

Brand new to HDFS here.

I've got this small section of code to test out appending to a file:

```
val path: Path = new Path("/tmp", "myFile")
val config = new Configuration()
val fileSystem: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(config)
val outputStream = fileSystem.append(path)
outputStream.writeChars("what's up")
outputStream.close()
```

It is failing with this message:

```
Not supported
java.io.IOException: Not supported
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.append(ChecksumFileSystem.java:352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:1163)
```

I looked at the source for ChecksumFileSystem.java, and it seems to be hardcoded to not support appending:

```
@Override
public FSDataOutputStream append(Path f, int bufferSize,
    Progressable progress) throws IOException {
  throw new IOException("Not supported");
}
```

How to make this work?  Is there some way to change the default file system to some other implementation that *does* support append?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to actually run a real hadoop namenode and datanode.  I am new to hadoop and did not realize this.  Without this, it will use your local filesystem which is a ChecksumFileSystem, which does not support append.  So I followed the blog post [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-install-cdh-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/) to get it up and running on my system, and now I am able to append.

Answer (score 1):

The append method has to be called on outputstream not on filesystem. filesystem.get() is just used to connect to your HDFS. First set dfs.support.append as true in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.support.append</name>
       <value>true</value>
</property>
```

stop all your demon services using stop-all.sh and restart it again using start-all.sh. Put this in your main method.

```
String fileuri = "hdfs/file/path"
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(fileuri),conf);
FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(new Path(fileuri));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
writer.append("I am appending this to my file");
writer.close();
fs.close();
```